# Zsh CORRECT option is unaware of AUTO_CD and CDABLE_VARS

Tags: zsh

Is there a way to make the CORRECT option aware of AUTO_CD and CDABLE_VARS? In this example, I would expect correction to not be triggered. Could this be a bug?

```
> setopt autocd
> setopt cdablevars
> setopt correct 
> vimz=/var
> vimz
zsh: correct 'vimz' to 'vim' [nyae]?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was a bug/limitation in zsh that was fixed by [that commit](https://sourceforge.net/p/zsh/code/ci/a98e13ed1f9c525947088ef9631e19e5477d5171/) on 2019-08-29, with [corresponding message on the mailing-list](https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2019/msg00750.html) after [you reported it there](https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2019/msg00747.html) (thanks for that).

The fix is included in zsh version 5.8 (dev 5.7.1-test-1) and newer.